# Typescript error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"allName" | `allName.${number}.nestedArray`' in react hook form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I am working on the react hook form with typescript. My data structure looks array within array. so I try to use the `useFieldArray`

```
allName: [
    {
      name: "useFieldArray1",
      nestedArray: [
        { name1: "field1", name2: "field2" },
        { name1: "field3", name2: "field4" }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "useFieldArray2",
      nestedArray: [{ name1: "field1", name2: "field2" }]
    }
  ]
```

But when I try to set the name for the input like `allName[${nestIndex}].nestedArray`
I got the below warning.

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"allName" | `allName.${number}.nestedArray`'
```

Here I have attached the code sandbox link of my code.
https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-buck-iyqoc?file=/src/nestedFieldArray.tsx:504-537
How to fix this issue?

Comment: Your `nestedIndex` prop for `NestedFieldArray` is declared as type `string`, yet it's getting passed a number in the `<Fields>` component. It should probably be a number. The square brackets are probably unnecessary, and the name should be `\`allName.${nestIndex}.nestedArray\` as const` to match what [the documentation](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usefieldarray/) says.

Comment: @Calvin I made the changes that you suggest. Still I got the same issue.
https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-fermi-rvuzq?file=/src/nestedFieldArray.tsx

Comment: @Calvin problem with the 15th line

Comment: Does appending `as const` to that line work?

Comment: @Calvin That error is resolved now. I am facing an issue that, my form is not rendered with the default value. Inputs are empty at the initial time. But, the default value got some valid values.
https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-cori-36ose?file=/src/nestedFieldArray.tsx

Comment: On line 7 of input.tsx you have `value={field.value ?? ""}`. This sets the value and thus the `defaultValue` will never get displayed. Are you trying to make a form using controlled or uncontrolled components? If uncontrolled, you need to pass the input the props returned from `register()` and possibly forward some refs.

Comment: @Calvin in the usecontroller's field value is undefined.  I am not sure that, how to fix this

Comment: and i am trying to do the controlled components

Comment: I am not as familiar with using controlled components when using react-hook-form. Try taking a look this [documentation on the Controller component](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller) and maybe this too: https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/discussions/3572

Comment: I'm experiencing this type error as well, I don't know if react-hook-form team decided for us if we can have or not nested field arrays within field arrays.

Comment: @shackra I flattened all the nested array like [{ name1: "field1", name2: "field2" , name:'useFieldArray1'},
        { name1: "field3", name2: "field4" , name: 'useFieldArray1'}, { name1: "field1", name2: "field2" , name:'useFieldArray2'},
        { name1: "field3", name2: "field4" , name: 'useFieldArray2'}]. and render my form. When i submit i convert the form data to expected structure.

Answer (score 4):

Hello couple things I see,

> `1`) you have to `cast` it to that type that you exported or `const` the `compiler needs to be aware of the type` explicitly.

> `2`) I also noticed you have ` vs `'` ticks/quote

> `3`. ps. `const` works on the later/newer version of Tyspescript compiler, but for older versions if you change it `any` it should work!

```
 //option 1
 name: `allName.${nestIndex}.nestedArray` as const

// option 2 for older versions
name: `allName.${nestIndex}.nestedArray` as any


 // or if assigning a variable, but it wont work in your code
 // let name = <const> `allName.${nestIndex}.nestedArray`
```